# Rendering GIF in swift 5.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I am rendering GIF in UITableview but due to rendering gif, it is taking time(like it's stuck for a moment every time when I scroll up and down). For rendering gif, I am using this line of code

```
UIImage.gifImageWithName("funny")
```

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/08/load-gif-image-in-swift_22.html

So please suggest to me if any other solution for it. Thanks

Comment: Try loading of gif images in background thread. Its just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) and render gif with memory efficient way.